# server not parsing php file called from jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im using a basic `jquery` `ajax` call.

I make a call to a `php` file without input parameters with option datatype set to `json`.

I want the server to parse the `php` which queries a table in a `mysql` db, convert it to `array` and finally `encode` it to `json` and `return`.

I tried a test call from the browser by copying the `php` file `url` in the `address` field, and it shows that it works, since I can see a blank page with all the rows of the table in `json` formatting.

Instead, when calling from my `javascript` code the `$.ajax` call fails with error

`Requested JSON parse failed`

which means `ajax` call was expecting `json` (since I set option datatype to that) but received another format.

So I tried removing the datatype option from the call, and lo and behold I got a response `success`, but what did I received from my `php` file?

Well, it was the whole code in the file, like the server doesn't parse it cause it thinks it's plain text.

Is there a way out of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: are you sure the request is failing and it's not just corrupt json causing this? show your actual server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, I may answer my own question, I was debugging jquery from visual studio, which automatically instatiates an iis web server, and it explains why it was treating php files like text files. Obviously under apache everything works fine.
Sorry for taking your time....

Answer (score 2):

Send also content header with json data

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ajax function is expecting a JSON encoded document so you have to send a header with the response saying that the response contains JSON. Something like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // All your code here
    echo json_encode($someArray);
?>
```